# How do I keep track of the string length?

Tags: c, printf

I have a function with command line argument:

```
int main(int argc, string argv[])
```

I want to store my argument so I declare a variable:

```
string key = argv[1];
```

It's intended to be string and I want to transfer this string to alphabetic index from ASCII ('A' = 0, 'B' = 1, etc.). So I go like this

```
printf("key length %lu\n", strlen(key));

for (j = 0, n = strlen(key); j < n; j++)
{
    if(isupper(key[j]))
    {
        key[j] = key[j] - 65;
    }
    else
    {
        key[j] = key[j] - 97;
    }
}

printf("key length %lu\n", strlen(key));
```

But somehow, those two prints give me different value. Seems like second `printf` will always give me `1`. I can't figure out why it is happening. I can print `key[j]` with `%i`, but when I ask for `%c`, it leaves only blank spaces. What am I missing here?

Comment: Side note: `printf("key length %lu\n", strlen(key))` ---> `printf("key length %zu\n", strlen(key))`

Comment: Side note #2: The normal signature of main should use ``const char *args[]`` with emphasis on the const. I am not really sure if modifying the args is defined behavior...

Comment: When you subtract the symbol table from each character, you convert your string into an array of integers. It is no longer a C string, so string-handling functions can no longer be used on it.

Comment: `string`!? What is this datatype?

Comment: @StoryTeller probably part of the `cs50.h` library. I'm pretty sure it uses `typedef char *string` in there.

Comment: the parameter `argv[]` is an array of pointers to strings, not an array of strings. so the signature for `main()` is not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your code the first `A` or `a` in the string will be a `0` after your loop, i.e. null terminator. So `strlen` will stop counting chars after null terminator is triggered.

As already commented, the right format specifier for `size_t` type is `%zu`

Another little thing: to be more readable you could use `'A'` and `'a'` to subtract to your string chars instead of "magic numbers", like

```
key[j] = key[j] - 'A';
```

Comment: @ChrisMaes A copule of seconds. ;) +1 for you

Answer (score 2):

`strlen` will count the number of characters until it encounters the `\0` character. I guess the word you give contains an **A** or an **a**? In that case you will put a **0** in your string, and `strlen` will stop there.

Answer (score 2):

When you transform your string you map `A` and `a` to `0`. `0` also happens to be the value of the string terminator character, so when you do `strlen` on the transformed string it will stop counting when it reaches the first `A`/`a`.

To track the length you need to remember the length from the `strlen` you did before the transformation and pass it along with the buffer.